# React, material ui paper max-width override

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, material-ui, angular-material

I want to change the paper module's max-width value but has a root css that I can't override.
In the console looks like this:

.css-1t1j96h-MuiPaper-root-MuiDialog-paper {
max-width: 600px;

I have a same popup like this. But there is no that root css, I will comment that popup in comment.

```
  return (
    <Container className='formContainer' >
        <Paper elevation={1} style={paperStyle}>
            <form className='addOrEditForm' noValidate autoComplete="off">
              <Box
              component="form"
              sx={{
                  '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 2 },
              }}
              noValidate
              autoComplete="off"
              >
                <div>
                     //some input field               
                </div>
              </Box>
            </form>
        </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

I tried makeStyles, sx, basic css.

Comment: Not sure what you tried with `sx`, but  `<Paper sx={{maxWidth:100}}>` should work, unless you are overwriting it in the `style={paperStyle}`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. Interestingly, if I set the value to 100, I see a change on the form, but the value of the root does not change. (I tried without style={paperStyle} too)